# Online Resources for Korean Spelling and Grammar Check

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, resources

What are your recommendations for tools that can help save time and headache when checking your Korean spelling, vocabulary, grammar, etc?

I believe a well made utility can be productive in getting certain types of questions - especially on an objective and technical sense like spelling and grammar - answered before consulting other linguistic experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For self-checking in a quick and straight forward manner, I highly recommend users to utilize the following:

Online Korean grammar engine by Busan university

> http://speller.cs.pusan.ac.kr/

For Mac users, downloadable utility (the blog post does a good walk-through albeit in Korean)

> http://macnews.tistory.com/810

If anyone can provide resources that are English friendly, I would be interested to find out more.